# C++ export thread_local global variable in C?

Tags: c++, include, thread-local

I'm developing a shared library using C++ and want a C header for user to include.

The library exports a thread_local global variable, so that an `extern` instruction should be writed in the header.

And this variable only be modified in library code (C++), and readonly in user's code (C language).

However C language doesn't have `thread_local` keyword.
So, Any idea about it?

Does the simply `extern type variable` is definitely correct?

And the case of modifying the variable in C ? Does everything still works?

Comment: Don't "export" the global variable, and instead use a function to get the current value of the variable?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course it works. But I'm just interested in this situation.

Comment: May the key problem is how the thread_local variable stored and accessed, just like normal variables but in a special mapped address space ? Or some magic ?

Comment: If you use `extern` only, then you will have a single variable in the whole library, whereas in the case of using thread local storage, the compiler will allocate space in the thread local memory to reserve and initialize the variable. In C you can achieve this through `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_setspecific`. Note how they provide this functionality following what @Someprogrammerdude suggests you to do. `malloc` does something similar, in the sense that each thread has its own memory pool stored in their TLS.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just thought thread_local may could be implemented via mapping the same virtual address to different physical address for different pthread, but I found `pthread_create` uses [CLONE_VM](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) blocking this way. And I also found [this paper](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/05/02/the-hidden-performance-cost-of-accessing-thread-local-variables) tells `thread_local` getter indeed processes some special codes rather than normal access. Anyway, I will use wrapper. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the variable is referenced relative to a pointer that is stored in the thread context. May be even a register. When a thread is created the data is allocated and the pointer is initialised to point to it. (Space will always be required for the context.) When the process switches from one thread to another the current context is stored a different context restored, including the indirect pointer. If you do not use the correct type the patching at link time will not be correct and the correct area of memory will not be used. I do not know if the patching will just be wrong, or if the linker knows the symbol type, giving ether an explicit error or just seeing the global as undefined. Ie i don't know if it sees it as a different symbol, the same symbol but declared with conflicting types, or the same symbol, but will the mixed up reference methods will be break the code.